# vim: Bind leader key to open .vimrc in a different path

Tags: vim

I have my `.vimrc` in a different path, that I source from my main `~/.vimrc` (so I can share same settings across Windows, bash on Windows, etc).

I'm trying to write something in the `.vimrc` in question, that would make a hotkey for editing said `.vimrc`, without hard coding the path.

What I currently have is this:

```
let g:vimrc_path = expand('<sfile>')
:map <Leader>v exec(":e " + g:vimrc_path + "<CR>")
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything.  I've verified that `g:vimrc_path` is the right value, and that the `<Leader>v` ends up being called by subbing in echo messages, but I'm not wrapping my head around why the variable I'm trying to define doesn't get expanded correctly.

Comment: String concatenation character in vimL is `.` not `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- String concatenation is done with `.`, not with `+`, which performs coercion into numbers and addition. But `:execute` takes multiple arguments (which it space-separates), so you don't actually need this here.
- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Also, I doubt you need visual and operator-pending modes (`:help map-modes`), so define this just for normal mode.
- `:exec[ute` is an Ex command, so for a normal-mode mapping, you need to *first* enter command-line mode. So `:exec 'edit'` instead of `exec ':edit'`.
- Also, this is not a function (though Vim 8 now also has `execute()`), so the parentheses are superfluous.
- The `<silent>` avoids the printing of the whole command (you'll notice the loading of the vimrc file, anyway); it's optional.
- The `fnameescape()` ensures that pathological path names are also handled; probably not necessary here.

```
let g:vimrc_path = expand('<sfile>')
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>v :execute 'edit' fnameescape(g:vimrc_path)<CR>
```

#### Alternative

As the script path is static, you can move the variable interpolation from runtime (mapping execution) to mapping definition, and get rid of the variable:

```
execute 'nnoremap <Leader>v :edit' fnameescape(expand('<sfile>')) . '<CR>'
```

Comment: This worked, so first thanks for that, but I also appreciate the breakdown of the component pieces.  10/10 would subscribe to your newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in vimscript are concatenated with `.`, *not* with `+`. For example:

```
:echo "Hello"." world!"
```

will echo

> Hello world!

If you were to type

```
:echo "Hello" + " world!"
```

vim would echo

> 0

This is because the `+` operator is *only* for numbers, so vim attempts to cast these strings to numbers. If you were to run

```
:echo "3" + "1"
```

vim would echo "4".

So basically, you just need to change

```
:map <Leader>v exec(":e " + g:vimrc_path + "<CR>")
```

to

```
:map <Leader>v exec(":e ".g:vimrc_path."<CR>")
```

Another problem you might have not seen is that `"<CR>"` evaluates to the literal text `"<CR>"`, so it only messes up your function. If you want a literal carriage return, you would need a backslash. *However*, you definitely do not want to do this! Seriously, try it out and see.

You can see the issue. It looks for a file that has a literal carriage return at the end of the filename! There is a very simple fix though. Remove the `"\<cr>"` completely. Since `:exec` runs ex commands by default, the carriage return (and the colon too for that matter) are unnecessary.

Also, as a nitpick,

1. The parenthesis are not needed for the "exec" function, and
2. Use `nnoremap` instead to avoid recursive mappings.

Taking all of this into consideration, I would simplify it to

```
:nnoremap <Leader>v :exec "e ".g:vimrc_path<cr>
```

Comment: You've overlooked the biggest flaw: Without a leading `:`, the `exec` will be interpreted as the normal mode `ex` and `ec...` motions and commands.